# Iframe injection Attack - Javascript Mass

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe, code-injection

I would like to know if I can help create the regular expression for this line of code:

```
document.write('<iframe src="http://msn.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="7" width="7"></iframe>');
```

what happens is that a virus enter and edit all javascript files (. js) by adding at the end the line of code you mention. I'll use the script of this publication (http://crear-paginas-web.blogspot.com/2010/04/archivos-php-hackeados-con.html) but I need the new regular expression to implement. I've been trying to make it on my own but as I know has paid off:

```
/document[.]write\(\'\<iframe src\=\"http\:\/\/(msn.com)\" scrolling\=\"auto\" frameborder\=\"no\" align\=\"center\" height\=\"7\" width\=\"\7\"\>\<\/iframe\>+\'\);/
```

I hope you can help me, greetings.

Comment: Well, if you have a virus, I'd suggest scanning and cleaning up your server then restoring a backup.

Comment: Hello, the virus already was removed but now I need to clean the files that have been infected and to use the script you need to use meciono regular expression code that inserted the virus.

Comment: What's wrong with SO lately? -4 votes on a new user's question without even a single comment of feedback? This is really sad, to not say stupid.

Comment: I am very grateful, I have no reputation so I can not vote in favor, do not know who is the bad person who voted against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will match your specific string:

```
/document\.write\('<iframe src="http:\/\/msn\.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="7" width="7"><\/iframe>'\);/
```

http://regexr.com?32k7v

Note that if there is a minimum variation in the markup then it won't match. You'll most likely have replace the address with a properly escaped version of your offending script's address.

If you want a more general regex, to match all `document.write` which writes `iframe` with a given URL, you can use:

```
/document\.write\('<iframe.*?src="http:\/\/msn\.com".*?><\/iframe>'\);/
```

http://regexr.com?32k85

Note that if your website has many pages, it will be hard to be sure that there are no remains of the attack. Hence I'd still suggest restoring a backup of the files if you have any.

Comment: Hey anonymous downvoter, you realize my answer actually answers the question right? What if you provide some piece of feedback on what is wrong with this answer instead of just randomly casting downvotes?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help and achieve served me clean my files. A regular expression you gave me I just had to add \ before the 'internal to work properly.
I am very grateful, I have no reputation so I can not vote in favor, do not know who is the bad person who voted against.

Comment: Here is the link to the final code: [REGEXR](http://regexr.com?32kag) >>>>> `/document\.write\(\'<iframe src="http:\/\/msn\.com" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" align="center" height="7" width="7"><\/iframe>\'\);/`

Comment: `/document\.write\(\'<iframe.*?src="http:\/\/msn\.com".*?><\/iframe>\'\);/`